# Dealing with a precision error when generating probability distribution in python

Tags: python

In the context of a model I'm generating, I at one point need to generate a probability distribution from a an array of real numbers. I'll leave out the relevant details, but essentially have a function (we'll just call it "f" for now), that generates an array of n floats:

```
arr = [value_1, value_2, ..., value_n]
```

Now, these values are **proportional** to probabilities I next need to use in a multinomial sampling procedure, so the obvious approach is simply this:

```
result = np.random.multinomial(number_of_samples,arr/arr.sum())
```

But this (sometimes) doesn't work! Basically the sum of arr/arr.sum() ends up being greater than 1. In principle this should be mathematically impossible, but I'm assuming this boils down to a floating-point precision issue. Here's a trivial example of how this can happen:

```
In [58]: arr = np.array([1/20.]*20)

In [59]: arr/arr.sum()
Out[59]:
array([ 0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,
    0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,
    0.05,  0.05])

In [60]: (arr/arr.sum()).sum()
Out[60]: 1.0000000000000002
```

So long story short, my question is how best to deal with this. I can cheat by simply adding a very small number to the sum, i.e.:

```
probs = arr / (arr.sum()+0.000001)
```

But this is really hackish, and I fear it may introduce further unwanted precision issues. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by reading https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

In a nutshell, floating point can't really represent 0.05. The effect is minute:

```
>>> repr(1/20.)
'0.05'
>>> repr(sum([1/20.]*20))
'1.0000000000000002'
```

The correct solution is to define the desired precision for each mathematical operation, calculate the round errors of each step and round accordingly when necessary.

In your case, you can round to 5 digits since you're only adding a few numbers.

```
>>> repr(round(sum([1/20.]*20),5))
'1.0'
```

But for more complex calculations which need to be correct, you will have to do the error assessment.